# mysqli dynamic generated table with link that opens form with all values from row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this table:(megaoverzicht.php) (I left out the part where it connects to the db)

```
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Formulier Id</th><th>Domeinnaam</th><th>Bedrijfsnaam</th><th>Datum</th><th>Periode</th><th>Subtotaal</th><th>Dealernaam</th><th>Offerte Maken</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['formuliernummer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['domeinnaam'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['bedrijfsnaam'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['periode'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> &euro; " . $row['subtotaal'] . "</td>";        
  echo "<td>" . $row['dealercontactpersoon'] . "</td>";     
  echo "<td><a href='offertemaken.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Offerte Maken </a></td>";            
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I want to open offertemaken.php when the user clicks on Offerte Maken. It needs to open the form with the data from that row(id).

This is the code from (offertemaken.php)(I left out the part where it connects to the db)

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$data = 'SELECT * FROM cypg8_overzicht WHERE id="$id"';  
  $query = mysqli_query($con,$data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysqli_error()); 
  $data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query); 
?>
<form>
<div class="formcontainer" onmousemove="">
 <input type="text" name="datum" id="datum"                                                                     value="<?php echo $data2[datum]?>">
 <input type="text" name="formuliernummer" id="formuliernummer"                             value="<?php echo $data2[formuliernummer]?>">
 <input type="text" name="periode" id="periode"                                                             value="<?php echo $data2[periode]?>">
 <input type="text" name="domeinnaam" id="domeinnaam"                                                   value="<?php echo $data2[domeinnaam]?>">
 <input type="text" name="bedrijfsnaam" id="bedrijfsnaam"                                           value="<?php echo $data2[bedrijfsnaam]?>">
 <input type="text" name="dealercontactpersoon" id="dealercontactpersoon"           value="<?php echo $data2[dealercontactpersoon]?>">     
</div><!--/.formcontainer-->
</form>
```

I cant get it to work. I am missing something I think! I make an error in the codes below:

```
  echo "<td><a href='offertemaken.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Offerte Maken </a></td>";
```

---

```
  $id=$_POST['id'];
  $data = 'SELECT * FROM cypg8_overzicht WHERE id="$id"';
```

I have been looking at a lot of tutorials but cant understand what i am doing wrong. Here a list to show that i am not just asking but actually have been looking for a solution by myself.

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/341921/-php-mysqli-update-database-using-id-syntax-help-requested-
http://www.codeofaninja.com/2012/01/phpmysqli-update-record.html

I have looked at many more but i don’t want to bother all of you with an extreme long list of links. And i am not allowed because my rep is not big enough! Dont downvote me please!

**Question**
I want to open offertemaken.php when the user clicks on Offerte Maken. It needs to open the form with the data from that row(id)?

**Edit 1 Getting closer to the endresult**
I found out(thanks to Cuba32) that the link in megaoverzicht.php was doing nothing so i changed the following

```
  <a href='offertemaken.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>
```

to

```
  <a href='offertemaken.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>
```

Now it is creating these kind of links:

something/formulieren/overzichten/offertemaken.php?id=24

This is a good thing(i think) but the form that opens is blank so offertemaken.php is doing nothing with the id???

**Edit 2** (Thanks to Cube32)

Since yesterday the code has changed quite a bit. I belive that megaoverzicht.php is finished it sends the link as described in edit 1. The only problem is know in offertemaken.php. Below i will put in the code.

```
 $con = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
 if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

 $id=$_GET['id'];
 if($data = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT * FROM cypg8_overzicht WHERE id="?"'))
 {

 /* bind parameters for markers */
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($data, "s", $id);

 /* execute query */
 mysqli_stmt_execute($data); 
 $data2 = mysqli_stmt_fetch($data);
```

But this code gives me the following error.

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in line 31. Line 31:

```
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($data, "s", $id);
```

I dont know how to solve this part. I will offcourse be looking on the internet to try and find a solution but if anyone knows it please post it. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 3**<= No more error (Thanks to Your Common Sense)

by changing `WHERE id="?"'` into `WHERE id=?'` i no longer have the error. But still it is not showing anything in the input fields

**Edit 4**<= Getting to confused and going back to original code.

Thanks for everyone who got me so far. But I can't see the forest anymore through the trees. I am going back to the original code and try to solve that. So the code is now as follows:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$data = 'SELECT * FROM cypg8_overzicht WHERE id="$id"';  
  $query = mysqli_query($con,$data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysqli_error()); 
  $data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

But this gives the following errors inside the input fields:

**Notice**:  Use of undefined constant formuliernummer - assumed 'formuliernummer' in **offertemaken.php** on line **37**

This error goes for all the input fields.

**Edit 5**
Fixed this by changing `<?php echo $data2[formuliernummer]?>` to `<?php echo $data2['formuliernummer']?>` but it is still not showing the information.

**Edit 6 THE SOLUTION**

I added the answer to the question below. Just look for answer written by HennySmafter.

**Thanks to:**

Cube32, SITDGNymall, Your Common Sense. Thanks all of you for helping me find the solution.

Comment: Dude. What's the matter with deleting your own questions?

Comment: Simple I can't figure it out. You probably have the best intensions but there is a bit of history between the two of us. And I have the idea that you do not like mine questions or me. This question was the entire time 2points and you give a comment and suddenly it is 1point. Maybe you have nothing to do with this but it is strange. Why I delete questions that are incorrect or no longer usable is because I don't want to have negative questions. Remember the -6 question that blocked me from using this site. I love this site and the users. It helped me out many times. And yes I do not know it all

Comment: That's why I ask help here. So please help or leave me be. For someone with a rep of over 60k you can have a couple of negative questions. I can only have 3 and I always try to give as much information as possible and to ask the right thing. PS the deleted question was kind of a duplicate from here.

Comment: The question you deleted had no negative votes. And it was intended to help someone else with the same problem. But you deleted it with no reason. Please understand that this site is not your private help desk. Don't take your questions as your private property. Other people contributed in them, as well as someone else may benefit from them. Such a selfish behavior will likely lead you to the consequences you are trying to avoid.

Comment: You are right about that. I found out that it is also possible to undelete it. So it is back to read for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but i found the answer.

**megaoverzicht.php**

```
echo "<td><a href='offertemaken.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Offerte Maken </a></td>";
```

**offertemaken.php**

```
 // Check whether the value for id is transmitted
 if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

 // Put the value in a separate variable
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 // Query the database for the details of the chosen id
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cypg8_overzicht WHERE id = $id");

 // Check result
 // This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
 if (!$result) {
 $message = "Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($result) . "\n";
 $message .= "Whole query: " . $query;
 die($message);
 }

 // Use result
 // Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
 // One of the mysql result functions must be used
 // See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(),etc.
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 echo $row['formuliernummer'] . "\n";
 echo $row['domeinnaam'] . "\n";
 echo $row['bedrijfsnaam'] . "\n";
 echo $row['datum'] . "\n";
 echo $row['periode'] . "\n";

 }
 } else {
 die("No valid id specified!");
 }
```

It is not showing the values in the input boxes because there are no input boxes into the echo but those can be easily added I imagine.

Answer (score -1):

*In reference to the edit 1:*

You are referencing the variables by association, but are outputing the mysql as a default array. instead of

```
$data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Try this:

```
$data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Or:

```
$data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Also, do you have error reporting turned on? If so, then if the array contains no data you should be getting warnings of some kind. If not, a good test is:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will warn you about any places where a variable is unset or a array is empty. Another good test is to simply echo out your query, which will tell you if there's any errors in the query itself(which can save some time). If you're not going to go the Prepared Statements route(which is highly encouraged), you can simply echo out $data into your script.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it gives an empty form. I added the error reporting function and all the textfields on offertemaken.php return the following code. <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant datum - assumed 'datum' in <b>offertemaken.php</b> on line <b>56</b><br /> Line 56 is `<input type="text" name="datum" id="datum"                     value="<?php echo $data2[datum]?>">`

Comment: Line 56 should say:<input type="text" name="datum" id="datum" value="<?php echo $data2['datum']?>

Comment: Thank you for input. I found out another solution. I found a script which was not entirely the right script but it gave me a notch in the right direction. It was MySQL so I changed this script to MySQLi added my own details and combined it with another script and suddenly I saw results. I posted the solution on this page.